# Generate an APK file from an AAB file (Android app bundle)

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, android-app-bundle

Is there a way to generate an [APK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file from an [Android Application Bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_App_Bundle) (AAB) via Terminal or using [Android Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio)?

Comment: The supplied answers below only talk about how to generate an APKS file, which is straight out of the bundletool documentation. Has anyone found a way to get an actual APK (not APKS) file out of a bundle?

Comment: @CaptainForge my answer does exactly that!
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57149405/5284155

Answer (score 168, accepted):

> By default, the IDE does not use app bundles to deploy your app to a
> local device for testing

Refer to the [bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool) command.

For the debug APK command,

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

For the release APK command,

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
    --ks=/MyApp/keystore.jks
    --ks-pass=file:/MyApp/keystore.pwd
    --ks-key-alias=MyKeyAlias
    --key-pass=file:/MyApp/key.pwd
```

I have been using the following commands while testing my release build for AAB:

1. Download the `bundletool` JAR file from [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases) (Latest release* → *Assets* → *bundletool-all-version.jar* file). Rename that file to *bundletool.jar*
2. Generate your AAB file from Android Studio, e.g.: *myapp-release.aab*
3. Run the following command:

   ```
   java -jar "path/to/bundletool.jar" build-apks --bundle=myapp-release.aab --output=myapp.apks --ks="/path/to/myapp-release.keystore" --ks-pass=pass:myapp-keystore-pass --ks-key-alias=myapp-alias --key-pass=pass:myapp-alias-pass
   ```
4. `myapp.apks` file will be generated
5. Make sure your device is connected to your machine
6. Now run the following command to install it on your device:

   ```
   java -jar "path/to/bundletool.jar" install-apks --apks=myapp.apks
   ```

If you need to extract a single `.apk` file from the `.aab` file, you can add a extra parameter, `--mode=universal` to the `bundletool` command:

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks \
    --mode=universal \
    --ks=/MyApp/keystore.jks \
    --ks-pass=file:/MyApp/keystore.pwd \
    --ks-key-alias=MyKeyAlias \
    --key-pass=file:/MyApp/key.pwd
```

And execute

```
unzip -p /MyApp/my_app.apks universal.apk > /MyApp/my_app.apk
```

This will generate a single */MyApp/my_app.apk* file that can be shared an installed by any device app installer.

Comment: "By default", Studio doesn't, but it can be done easily. See my answer below.

Comment: To nit, this doesn't actually answer the question. This generates an APKS file, not an APK file. An APKS file cannot be as easily installed to a device and requires the receiver of the APK to use the bundletool to install it, or go through AS, or something else that only a developer probably would know how to do.

Comment: @CaptainForge did you find any solution?

Comment: This command will just generate the APK Archive File (.apks) and we need to convert it to .zip format and extract it only to find plenty of APK files. The correct way is using a --mode:universal flag. I submitted an edit couple of times but unfortunately, they were rejected for a weird reason - "edit deviates from the original intent of the post". Common reviewers, I'm trying to complete the incomplete accepted answer.

Comment: Can you also add to your answer the possibility to do this in Android Studio with one click? That's much simpler than running these commands.

Comment: getting SEVERE: Input Future failed with Error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

**please help**

Comment: Can this tool also be used within an Android app? Can it be used to just install the aab file directly, without extracting to multiple apk files first?

Comment: use --mode=universal in bundletool command to create only one apk in the end

Answer (score 182):

So far nobody has provided the solution to get the APK from an AAB.

This solution will generate a universal binary as an apk.

1. Add `--mode=universal` to your `bundletool` command (if you need a signed app, use the --ks parameters as required).

   ```
    bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks --mode=universal
   ```
2. **MAIN STEP:** Change the output file name from `.apks` to `.zip`
3. Unzip and explore
4. The file `universal.apk` is your app

This universal binary will likely be quite big but is a great solution for sending to the QA department or distributing the App anywhere other than the Google Play store.

Comment: What if I want to generate the APK file within Android itself? Is it possible?

Comment: Can .apk be used to edit the app (or at least review the code) and then reupload to Google Play?

Comment: You can also directly build the APK corresponding to your connected device, by using build-apks with --connected-device, and then `bundletool install-apks`

Comment: I've made an app, it runs perfect local. So I build the apks file and use the bundletool as mentioned above. The app doesn't run. So there is something wrong with this method.

Answer (score 75):

Ok here is the complete way I had to do:

1. Download `bundletool-all-0.10.3.jar` from this [link](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases), download the latest version available
2. Create an app bundle using android studio and locate its path:

   In my case its `E:\Projects\Android\Temp\app\build\outputs\bundle\debug\app.aab`
3. Copy the bundletools jar to some location and get its path

In my case its `E:\Temp\bundletool-all-0.6.0.jar`

Use this command:

`java -jar "BUNDLE_TOOL_JAR_PATH" build-apks --bundle="BUNDLE_PATH" --output=YOUR_OUTPUT_NAME.apks`

In my case it will be

```
    java -jar "E:\Temp\bundletool-all-0.6.0.jar" build-apks \
        --bundle="E:\Projects\Android\Temp\app\build\outputs\bundle\debug\app.aab" \
        --output=out_bundle_archive_set.apks
```

4. This will create a file `out_bundle_archive_set.apks` , rename it to .zip `out_bundle_archive_set.zip` , extract this file and done You will have multiple **apk** files

To install directly on external device  use :

java -jar `"E:\Temp\bundletool-all-0.6.0.jar" install-apks --apks=out_bundle_archive_set.apks`

Check this [blog post](https://medium.com/mindorks/android-app-bundle-part-2-bundletool-6705b50bea4c) for more info . also check out [official site](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool)

Comment: Renaming `.apks` to `.zip` and unzipping it were the parts I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: SEVERE: Input Future failed with Error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, a few more flags will be required. `--ks` and `--ks-key-alias` with values
`--ks="path_to_your_keystore"` and `--ks-key-alias="key_alias_from_android_studio"`

Answer (score 21):

People have already explained on how to do this with the command-line. For completion, I thought I'd also show the way to do it via the UI in Android Studio.

When you open your "Run/Debug Configurations", you can select **"APK from app bundle"** (instead of "Default APK").

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Not able to build APK form aab , getting the following error "Install failed.
Installation failed
<a href='rerun'>Rerun</a>"

Comment: After Shift + F10 it will install an application to a device, not generate an apk.

Comment: How to set the location of the aab?

Answer (score 18):

> [Refer Geek Dashboard for more info](https://www.geekdashboard.com/extract-apk-files-from-aab/).

For those who are looking to generate a single universal APK file from your Android App Bundle, you must use `--universal` flag while running the `build-apks` command.

```
java -jar bundletool.jar build-apks --bundle=your_app.aab --output=your_app.apks --mode=universal
```

Where 
**bundletool.jar** is the bundletool jar file you downloaded [here](https://github.com/google/bundletool/releases)

**your_app.aab** is the Android App Bundle of your App

**your_app.apks** is the output APKs Archive File that will be generated once you run the command.

While running the above command make sure you place **bundletool.jar** and **your AAB file** in the same folder.

Now, you need to change the your_app.**apks** file format to your_app.**zip** and extract it to find the **universal.apk** file

[image]

**Note**: Use `–overwrite` flag to overwrite the APKs file if there is already one with the same name. Otherwise, `bundletool` command will throw you a fatal error.

Comment: getting SEVERE: Input Future failed with Error
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

please help

Answer (score 17):

on mac it can be easily done using homebrew

```
brew install bundletool
```

you can use the command below to generate apks

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=aab_path.aab --output=release.apks
```

above command generates apks file which can later be extracted to give various apk files. To see all generated files change the extension from .apks to .zip and just extract the files.

then you can install apk using this command on connected device

```
bundletool install-apks --apks=release.apks
```

Answer (score 13):

There's a tool called `bundletool`, which can create APK files out of your AAB file:

Find details about this tool on *[bundletool](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool)* (official documentation).

But here some highlights taken from that site:

**Building APK files**

When bundletool generates APK files from your app bundle, it includes them in a container called an APK set archive, which uses the *.apks* file extension. To generate an APK set for all device configurations your app supports from your app bundle, use the `bundletool build-apks` command, as shown below:

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

Note that the command above creates an APK set of unsigned APK files. If you want to deploy the APK files to a device, you need to also include your app’s signing information, as shown in the command below.

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
      --ks=/MyApp/keystore.jks
      --ks-pass=file:/MyApp/keystore.pwd
      --ks-key-alias=MyKeyAlias
      --key-pass=file:/MyApp/key.pwd
```

**Installing APKs**

```
bundletool install-apks --apks=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

**Generate a device-specific set of APKs**

```
bundletool build-apks --connected-device --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

Answer (score 8):

I have developed a windows tool for converting .aab files to .apk in Python.

It supports creating both debug and signed apk which can be directly installed to default android device connected through USB.

It uses google’s bundle tool in the backend.

https://aabtoapkconverter.com/

Edit:
The Source code is now available now on [github](https://github.com/idzresearch/aab-to-apk-converter).

This is first tool that I have developed and shared with the world. Hope it is useful. I am open to suggestions and bug reports.

[image]

Comment: Is it opensource?

Comment: I will be making it's source code available on github in next 1-2 days

Comment: Source code is now available on github. Link is added in the answer.

Comment: Does this make universal APKs? Don't see any option if one wants to get separate APKs or a universal one

Comment: Nice little tool :)

Comment: Thank you. Terminal commands were throwing annoying errors that I didn't know how to resolve. This worked just fine. @GeorgeBirbilis - You probably figured it out by now but it seems this makes a single universal .apk (Indeed, in the github code, you can see the `--mode=universal` flag.)

Answer (score 3):

Here is what i did.
First thing is, i am on a Mac.
So in this official guide https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android, followed below steps.

1. Run this command `sudo keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-upload-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`
   you can change the name of my-upload-key to your choice
2. Setup the gradle variables as per the guide
3. Also do the same as per the guide for point "Adding signing config to your app's Gradle config"
4. Now rather than continuing (which will generate an AAB file) what you can do is below.

4.1 I open the same project(android folder) in Android Studio

4.2 From the `Menu Options > Build > Clean Project`

4.3 Click on the Make Project button and let it complete (if you can run using `npm run android`, then this should finish without any issues)
[Make Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjNLy.png)

4.4 Once done, click on `Menu options > Build > Generate Signed Bundle/APK...`
[Generate Signed Bundle/APK...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3yOC.png)

4.5 In the next Screen Choose APK radio button and Click Next
[Choose APK option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4gCp.png)

4.6 In the next screen, Browse to the keystore file which you generated as the first step, its password, alias name and its password, click Next.
[Final Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51C2c.png)

Wait for it to complete. You may see some errors but more importantly in the end you should get a popup in the right bottom corner saying "Locate". Click on that and you will find your app-release.apk.

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic Project .aab file convert to .apk by below commend

```
ionic cordova build android --release -- -- --packageType=apk
```

Answer (score -9):

I think this method much more efficient

[image]

Comment: Consider adding a more descriptive reply to go along with the screenshot.