# react native build release from .apk to .aab, how to send the app to the clients?

Tags: android, react-native, apk

It's been so long since I develop a mobile app in react native, when I'm developing before, I usually generate a release apk and send it to my clients so that they can test it and have experienced it, but now when I build a release in react native, it returns a `.aab` instead of `.apk`, how can I send my application to the clients when I only get `.aab` format on my project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate Apk file from aab file (android app bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It using for different android devices installation by google play store. that's why you can use apk build for manual installation.

You must use the below command for the testing build.

```
$ cd android
$ ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Comment: Please edit your answer, as referred by Paul Freeman. its the correct command.

Comment: If you are on windows then omit the `./`. It should be `gradlew assembleRelease` only.

Comment: The command from RN doc is `./gradlew bundleRelease` (https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android). Why and how is it different from `./gradlew assembleRelease` ? I noticed 1 thing when trying to create universal apk files: only `assembleRelease` allowed me to generate .apk file(s) directly, whereas `bundleRelease` didn't create anything in /android/app/build/outputs/apk/release

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned repeatedly in many places .aab file is efficient. But we need .apk for regular task (*except PlayStore*).

So:-

1. Create signed output of Android project [Link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android)
2. Use command `$ npx react-native run-android` for debugging.
3. Finally `$ npx react-native run-android --variant=release` [Link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android#testing-the-release-build-of-your-app), to create release version, which is created at *android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/**app.apk***
4. Go crazy

Answer (score 5):

Just for the information. If you upload the AAB to Google Play instead of the APK, it will lead to smaller download sizes. AAB lets Google Play create different APKs to different devices, based on the device screen density, language, and CPU architecture. So, if you're able to create AAB's, use them over APK's.

Answer (score 4):

```
cd android
./gradlew bundleRelease
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

The generated AAB can be found under

> android/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab

, and is ready to be uploaded to Google Play

Answer (score 0):

if you want to generate APK file instead of aab file using for Manual Testing then follow below steps.

```
 1. cd android
 2. ./gradlew clean
 3. ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Thanks.