# apk does not install after generated by bundletool

Tags: android, flutter, apk, android-install-apk

I followed [instructions](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#build-an-apk) to first generate app.aab per section **Offline using the bundle tool** , then, I am trying to generate the APK per [Extract device-specific APKs from an existing APK set](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool#generate_apks) and issued

```
java -jar .\bundletool-all-0.12.0.jar extract-apks --apks=.\samsung.apks --output-dir=.\my_samsung_APK_set.apks --device-spec=.\samsung.json
```

A folder is generated with name my_samsung_APK_set.apks and I can see multiple APKs there

```
base-arm64_v8a.apk
base-en.apk
base-master.apk
base-xxxhdpi.apk
```

I copied these files manually on the phone and when I try to install base-master.apk by tapping on it, I get "**App not installed**", what is wrong ? I tried tapping on other 3 files and those gives error **There was a problem parsing the package.** .

So which of these 4 files ( APK) is supposed to be tapped to install?

[image: files that are generated]

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you need to install the correct version for your specific device.

Comment: @joão-soares after I copy these files( 4 apk), which one should be tried to be installed ? or does I even need to copy all 4 apk files ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle See this and add universal mode to your bundletool command

Answer (score 2):

You need to install all these APKs together at the same time, you can't install just base-master.apk as the Android platform detects that the app is incomplete.

It is unfortunately not possible today to install all the APKs by tapping on them from the device. The only way is to install them is via a computer and a cable either via bundletool `install-apks` command (using the .apks files), or via the command `adb install-multiple`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be the only universal model available to install manually. *at least for now*.