# Is it possible to get app code from uploaded build?

Tags: flutter

I just had the unfortunate of losing my app source code. Is it possible to get it from google appbundle or apple build?

Comment: do you have apk?

Comment: @YasineRomdhane no, I uploaded it as an app bundle. But it seems there is an option to download app on play console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle) should help you turn your android app bundle into apk.
If you have the apk file, then it might be possible to turn it back into code. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6081365/15807780) might help you out.
**I'm not sure if this is gonna work or not but it's worth trying so keep me updated**

Let this be a lesson for you to use [Github](http://github.com) next time!