# Is it possible to convert bundle file to source code?

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

Not long ago, I have developed an android app and posted in google play store as a bundle file, but the source code is deleted due to my special circumstances. Now, I want to  update the app. Is it possible to bring back the source code using the bundle file in my google play console account?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert you aab to apk: [Generate Apk file from aab file (android app bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle)

Then you can decompile the apk file, but it won't be easy if the code has been obfuscated with proguard.
You can use a site like: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

In any case it is still a good help if you want to recreate the application, you can recover the layouts / strings and some code ...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can decompile the AAB bundle file using JDAX (https://androidrepo.com/repo/skylot-jadx-android-security--decompiler), which would save you the effort of the APK conversion as initial processing step.

However there are limitations as it was already stated by the first answer of this thread. As stated your main problem will be the code obfuscation, but its probably better to have some code template for recreation of the app, than do it all out of nothing.