# How to build a single apk (not ".apks") but is splitted by abi from aab?

Tags: java, android, gradle, apk

Originally I use build variants to build two apks: `myapp-armv7.apk` and `myapp-arm64.apk`, for the 32bit and 64bit architectures, respectively. For example, the 32bit apk only contains native `.so` files for 32bit, while the 64bit apk only contains those for 64bit.

However, now I not only want these two apk files, but also want a `myapp.aab` bundle. The question is, how to build the 32bit and 64bit apk from this aab bundle?

I have tried [Generate Apk file from aab file (android app bundle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle) . However, if I use `--mode=universal`, though I get an installable apk file, it contains both 32bit and 64bit `.so` files inside it, so it is really huge and we should not use it. If I do not use that flag, I get a bunch of apk files (i.e. an `.apks` file), but of course a user should only download one `.apk` file and click "install", so that is also not feasible.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, this is not workable. Universal mode + unzip is a trick to extract what we are familiar with - the `.apk`. However, other use cases of `BundleTool` produce `.apks` only, which is our only choice to install for per device. Therefore, I think your question is about how to deploy those `.apks` to test devices easily.

- For local install / CI&CD, use `bundletool install-apks` CLI just like what you did with `adb install`.
- For manual staging testing by QA, deploy the `.aab` to PlayStore internal testing channel, AppCenter testing channel, etc.

Comment: No, my question is not about deploying `apks` file. I really need `.apk` file.

Comment: Well...unfortunately no such existing tool to make it from aab to split apk. I also wonder if there is something can provide this feature. @ch271828n