# Cordova: Generate a release APK file instead of an AAB file

Tags: cordova

I am trying to generate a release apk file using [Cordova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Cordova) 11 with the *build.json* file. Cordova generates an AAB file instead of an APK file. Here is the command I have used:

```
cordova build android --release
```

Comment: What's the problem wit aab?

Comment: No problem with aab. I need release apk.

Comment: Did you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle ?

Comment: I am having the same problem. Tried using --packageType=apk with the --release option but didn't work...

Comment: related cordova issues: [#1387](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1387#issuecomment-1077823344), [#1369](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1369), [#1377](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1377#issuecomment-972409841)

Answer (score 29):

Finally, I have the answer! Use:

```
cordova build android --release -- --packageType=apk
```

Got this answer from a youtube user called Harag. Thank you Harag.

Comment: I executed this command (`cordova build android --release -- --packageType=apk`) but still got .aab file 

Comment: if you, like me, use cordova [through quasar](https://v1.quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-cordova-apps/build-commands) you might have to use `--` twice, like `npx quasar build -m cordova -T android -- -- --packageType=apk`

Answer (score 4):

Build with cordova command:

```
cordova build android --packageType=apk
```

It will create .apk in debug mode and depending on cordova version in release. You can also create .aab and use bundletool (see [android bundletool](https://developer.android.com/tools/bundletool)) to extract apks like this:

```
bundletool build-apks --bundle=/MyApp/my_app.aab --output=/MyApp/my_app.apks
```

Comment: Not sure about the first part... I ran it with the `--release` flag and it gave me: `platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk`

Comment: Probably cordova fixed this. I've changed the answer

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a Windows machine, the following is what worked for me:

Ionic:

```
ionic cordova build android --release "--" "--" --packageType=apk
```

Non-Ionic:

```
cordova build android --release "--" "--" --packageType=apk
```

The secret is to escape the `--`. I got this answer straight from the Cordova Support: *[Generate .apk instead of .aab file (Ionic Project) #1671](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1671)*

Comment: What worked for me with my non-Ionic app is: ```cordova build android --release "--" --packageType=apk``` (note the single ```"--"``` instead of the two suggested in this post).

Answer (score 1):

Confirming that the command that produced .apk is

```
cordova build android --release -- --packageType=apk
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using ionic with cordova, I am able to generate apk using -- twice

ionic cordova build android --prod --release -- -- --packageType=apk