# Install Android App Bundle on device over WiFi

Tags: ionic3, adb, android-app-bundle

How can I installed .AAB file with adb or other tool over a WiFi only connected Android 11 device?

I have been using something like:

```
adb.exe -s 192.168.1.120:5555 install -g some.apk
```

tried specifying the .aab instead of the .apk in my script but it won't accept it.

[image]

The ionic build process started building .aab is there a way to tell it build only .apk for a specific device?  I do not intend or wish to publish to the Google Play.

Thank you.

Comment: Please do not post code in a screenshot, jsut copy and paste the code into your question and format it as code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle

Comment: I put the relevant code initially I just forget to format it as code.  The link you pointed out is about using the bundletool.jar tool but I did not see it support handling a device over WiFi, which is how I have been using adb.exe against these WiFi-only connected android devices, (they don't connect over USB cable or at least Windows does not recognize them like it does when a phone is connected via USB cable).  Thank you for sharing.

Comment: Forget the Wifi part your problem is that an app bundle can't be directly installed. You first have to convert it to APK file(s) which then can be installed. App bundles are only designed for upload to Play Store. And let me say again please don't post screen shots that only contain text. I am talking about the black screen shot in your question. It only contains text you could have copied and paste.