# On Azure Devops - How to Unpack AAB (android app bundle) make our required changes, repack and sign AAB?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, apk, continuous-deployment, android-app-bundle

As Android App Bundle is now required for the store we need to update our CD pipeline process.

**Are there any tasks to help me do this?**

**I have been unable to find them or if need be how do I write custom tasks?**

**Any other things to look out for now we will be working with aab files instead of apk?**

We have a Xamarin project writing in visual studio.

As for the Build process,  I was able to find that I could use msBuild tasks to create an AAB file using the following, I have been unable to verify if this is a functioning AAB as I can't extract it until our release pipeline is also completed.

```
- task: XamarinAndroid@1
    displayName: 'Build aab'
    inputs:
      projectFile: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\<PATH_TO_ANDROID.csproj>
      outputDirectory: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
      configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
      clean: true
      msbuildVersionOption: latest
      msbuildArguments: '/p:JavaSdkDirectory="$(JAVA_HOME_11_X64)/" /t:SignAndroidPackage /p:AndroidNdkDirectory="$(androidNdkPath)" /p:AndroidKeyStore="True" /p:AndroidSigningKeyStore="$(keystore.secureFilePath)" /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass="$(keystore.password)" /p:AndroidSigningKeyAlias=$(key.alias) /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=$(keystore.password)'

...
...
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: 'Copy deliverables AAB to staging'
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\<PATH_TO_ANDROID>\bin\$(buildConfiguration)'
      #SourceFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)' 
      Contents: '*.aab'
      #TargetFolder: 'drop'
      TargetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
...
```

Then once in the CD release pipeline, currently we do the following:

[image]

I was thinking if we can't directly unpack an *.AAB file > make changes > repack >sign it > etc

Then maybe we could convert it to apk > do our other steps above > then convert it back to aab > sign it > etc

I have tried using this one
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DamienAicheh.bundletool-tasks&targetId=27528779-628c-46e8-9cf5-1848170d72d2

It seems like I was able to convert it from aab > apk (I can't verify truly until this whole process if completed) but then I wasn't able to find a way to repack it and sign it.

```
steps:
- task: DamienAicheh.bundletool-tasks.install-bundletool-task.InstallBundletool@1
  displayName: 'Install Bundletool'
  inputs:
    username: '******'
    personalAccessToken: '**********'

.....

#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘AndroidkeystoreFilePath.secureFilePath’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘AndroidKeyStorePassword’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘AndroidKeyStoreAlias’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972
#Your build pipeline references an undefined variable named ‘AndroidKeyStorePassword’. Create or edit the build pipeline for this YAML file, define the variable on the Variables tab. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=865972

steps:
- task: DamienAicheh.bundletool-tasks.aab-convert-to-universal-apk-task.AabConvertToUniversalApk@1
  displayName: 'Android App Bundle converter to universal Apk'
  inputs:
    aabFilePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_CI-Build-v2/Android/****-Signed.aab'
    keystoreFilePath: '$(AndroidkeystoreFilePath.secureFilePath)'
    keystorePassword: '$(AndroidKeyStorePassword)'
    keystoreAlias: '$(AndroidKeyStoreAlias)'
    keystoreAliasPassword: '$(AndroidKeyStorePassword)'
    outputFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_CI-Build-v2/Android/AAB_TO_APK'
```

Answer (score 0):

### As far as i know no, there is no way to unpack your .aab files.

This is a file format intended for distribution through Google Play only.

You could however add steps in your pipeline to **also** build and sign an .apk file which can be locally distributed and installed, so cou can use this for testing and whatever else you want.

For an example of a pipeline that builds and exports both .apk and .aab see [this example](https://medium.com/medialesson/build-your-xamarin-android-application-with-azure-devops-9ddba3d04774)

Edit: You can unpack your .aab to .apk, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53040047/generate-apk-file-from-aab-file-android-app-bundle?rq=1)