# Bypass INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android

I'm looking to verify if data migration from a very old version of my Android app stills works with the latest version.
However, installing the debug apk over the Play Store signed apk leads to the error in the title.
How can I bypass this in an emulator ?

I'm just looking to verify that data migration and don't want to re-install a bunch of framework and packages versions from years ago on my computer, potentially messing up the current setup just to generate an unsigned version of that old app version.
On the other hand, the apk is signed from the Play Store but I don't want to create a special version, upload it there and manage all these things, again potentially making mistakes and messing up production by doing all that manually instead of trusting CI/CD.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this worked :

- Download old aab
- Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57149405/8451248) to generate an apk
- Generate an aab manually
- Do the same as 2)

These apks will allow updating from one to the next without signing problems.