# Install button not working with my APK file

Tags: java, android, build, apk

I finish my first app, but i have a problem.
I tried to create my APK file, but the APK file create with "Generate Signed Bundle/APK" and "Build Bundle(s)/APK - Build APK" don't work.
In folder "MyApp/app" i don't see any APK file.
I only see an APK file in "MyApp\app\release" with an "app.aab" and output.json" files. But when I install this APK file on my phone, the "Install" button isn't pressed.

The Generate Signed APK is fine, 'cause I get a messagge that saying the APK file is created.
"Generate Signed APK
APK(s) generated successfully for 1 module:
Module 'app': locate or analyze the APK."

I don't know how to solve.

P.S. Sorry for my english, but I'm desperate and in a hurry.

I already tried "Generate Signed Bundle/APK" and Build Bundle(s)/APK - Build APK". They get me a APK but they don't work.

Answer (score 2):

## Kindly try to do as mentioned below,

> 1) Go to Build.
>
> > 2) Generate Signed Bundle/APK(If you want a release build & have a        keystore).
> >
> > > 3)Buid Bundle(s)/APK(s), if you just need a debug build for testing or something.
> > >
> > > > 4) Under the above options, you can find the Build APK option and you have to choose that for generating your APK file.
> > > >
> > > > > 5) You can find your APK under the Your Project Folder - > app -> build - > output -> apk -> debug/release
> > > > >
> > > > > > Reference link : https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing
> > > > > >             Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You generated successfully apk with Android app bundle that's why it is showing .aab apk file in release folder

*An Android App Bundle is a file (with the .aab file extension) that you upload to Google Play to support Dynamic Delivery.
*

findout answer here
[[Install Android App Bundle on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419286/install-android-app-bundle-on-device][1])

if this helps you , correct this answer