# How to Run aap file in android emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, emulation, qemu

I am build my project in android studio and I make bundle in android studio.

The bundle have aap file I think aap file and apk are same so how can I run aap file in android emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can install the AAP file. It's a bundle that can be only used by Google Play and other services like that.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate of.
[Install Android App Bundle on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419286/install-android-app-bundle-on-device/50465619)

Use this GitHub Repo
https://github.com/google/bundletool
to extract your apk from your bundle and then run it on your device.